# How to get the real URL behind a mask?

Tags: php, html

Such as www.domain.com/ which is actually www.domain.com/index.html, or index.php?default=1, for example.

Comment: You can't but using something like [chrome sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae) might tell you what framework or language is being used.

Comment: Maybe the `Content-Location` field in the http response header? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses

Comment: Why the downvotes? What's not legit about this question?

Comment: @Jonathan M, I don't know either. Thanks for your suggestions, it maybe the case for some domains, but not for the one I am checking. Thank you.

Comment: @user1166981, please update your post to show why you're trying to get this information.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way.

Why you need that?

Comment: There's slim chance from the end user side, but the question isn't specific enough... Perhaps he's trying to maintain a system and doesn't know where things point? In that case, I'd say check the .htaccess file

Comment: @user1166981 Ok, but please, improve your question. We cannot help you if you don't give us enough infos. The question as it is looks exactly what I thought.

Comment: @Lore.. What are you asking? How could I make the question any clearer? It is quite a straight forward problem which does not require a 'why' to understand I think.

Comment: @user1166981 Add details and explain why you need that. Tell us if you are talking about your site, your website or not. What kind of access do you have on this server, etc, etc.